# imagen html en android no se ajusta a la pantalla

Tags: css

la imagen no se adpata al tamaño de pantalla de cada dispositivo. En dispositivos como smartphones es necesario hacer zoom- para adaptar la imagen a la pantalla y en dispositivos grandes como tablets la imagen se rodea de un marco blanco, quedando mas pequeña que la pantalla.

La imagen queda como se muestra en estas fotos en dispositivos de distinto tamaño:

[image]

[image]

Esta es la etiqueta meta:

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.0; user-scalable=no;" name="viewport" /> <img src="url de la imagen" width="720" />
```

Gracias.

**Actualización**

Con la ayuda de @Guz ahora la imagen se ve entera, pero sigue sin ajustarse a la pantalla, a pesar de darle 100% de ancho.

Código actualizado:

```
<title></title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.0; user-scalable=1;" name="viewport" />
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family:helvetica;
  }

  img {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<img src=" https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uvk4w2uq6tuhsb4/dosisacenoalto.PNG?dl=0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo cómo esperas que sea responsiva si le estás dando un ancho fijo a la imagen:

```
<img src="url de la imagen" width="720" />
```

En su lugar deberías darle un ancho dinámico:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iPgiV2o.png"/>
```

**Actualización**

> Con la ayuda de @Guz ahora la imagen seve entera, pero sigue sin ajustarse a la pantalla, a pesar de darle 100% de ancho.

No le has dado un ancho completo, si no, **un ancho máximo**. Si quieres **que la imagen siempre ocupe el 100% del contenedor** entonces debes darle simplemente `width: 100%`.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/iPgiV2o.png"/>
```

Comment: Gracias!!funciona a medias, ahora la imagen se ve entera en la pantalla, pero no llega ajustar...

Comment: edito pregunta para mostar como queda ahora el codigo

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvzgl390f98eoyr/20170304_184819.jpg?dl=0  Asi se ve ahora

Comment: Si quieres que la imagen **siempre ocupe** el 100% del viewport entonces dale `width: 100%`.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta para que veas el código.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hx1ods1qmy7pf44/Screenshot_2017-03-04-20-56-20.png?dl=0                                                                                    Mucho mejor ahora. GENIAL!!Muchisimas gracias! Asi es como queda ahora. Crees que habrá algo en el código que impida que se ajuste del todo y que haya esos pequeños margenes blancos alrededor de la imagen. hay algo que pueda hacer para eliminarlos del todo? Seria lo ideal para que la pantalla quedase "limpia" del todo, viéndose solo imagen.

Comment: Por defecto los navegadores agregan márgenes y rellenos de acuerdo a la preferencia de ellos. Puedes eliminarlos poniendo lo siguiente en el top de tu CSS: `*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }`.

Comment: No olvides votar y/o marcar mi respuesta si ayudó a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: intentare esto ultimo y te cuento, muchas gracias.Ya l intente antes pero creo que  me deja marcar pero no votar, demasiado novato.Puedo hacer algo mas?

Comment: No amigo, así está bien. Ante cualquier duda o problema, no dudes en publicar aquí. Saludos y buen weekend.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0cut56iyfsmyu5/Screenshot_2017-03-05-09-53-11.png?dl=0                                                                                                       Genial de nuevo, me has salvado:margenes eliminados. Tan solo queda un pequeño margen superior que creo que es culpa del código. Creo que ese margen lo genera el código esperando algo de texto...como podría eliminarlo?, es decir, solo imagen, nada de texto.